# Battleship game AI guessing same thing

Tags: python

I have created a battleship game in Python. Currently, the game has a simple AI that randomly guesses a spot that it has not already guessed on the board to try and find the two block large battleship. I'm making the AI more intelligent by giving it a pattern to follow. To generate the AI's guess, I use the following code.

```
while X == 0 | Y == 0:
     X = 0
     Y = 0
     guess_col = guessCol(0, size - 1)
     guess_row = guessRow(0, size - 1)
     # Make sure the guess follows the pattern
     if (guess_col + guess_row)%2 != 1:
         X = 1
     # Make sure the spot has not already been guessed
     if board[guess_row][guess_col] != "~":
         Y = 1
```

The board looks like the following.

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
2 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
3 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
4 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
5 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
6 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
7 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
8 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
9 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

The pattern works perfectly, but the new AI now guesses spots it has already guessed, making it very inefficient and not-so-smart. I have also tried using `if board[guess_row][guess_col] == "~":`, but this causes the pattern to not work either. How can I make the AI guess only in spots it hasn't already guessed?

Comment: Do you ever change the value of `board[guess_row][guess_col]` to something other than `~`?  Show us that code.

Comment: @jwodder When the block is guessed, it is changed to X, and when the ship is hit it is changed to H. I have the full source code here: http://github.com/JellyBellyFred/BattleShip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
while X == 0 | Y == 0:
```

does not do what you think it does.  `|` is bitwise OR, and in Python (unlike the C family) it has higher precedence than `==`.  Thus, Python parses the line as:

```
while X == (0 | Y) == 0:
```

which is equivalent to:

```
while X == Y == 0:
```

which, due to chaining of comparison operators, is equivalent to:

```
while (X == Y) and (Y == 0):
```

which is equivalent to:

```
while (X == 0) and (Y == 0):
```

which is most certainly not what you meant to accomplish by writing `X == 0 | Y == 0`!

Instead of using bitwise OR, use logical OR, which in Python is spelled `or`:

```
while X == 0 or Y == 0:
```

Comment: Thanks! I would have never guessed that I must spell out `or`!